# How can I insert into two tables? One of them is for registering a log

Tags: php, mysql, logging, system, multiple-tables

I have a form, which will insert records into table `people`, and also, I want to register a **system log** by inserting into another table called `log`.

This is the form:

```
<form action="inserting.php" method="POST">
    
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="mother">
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert">

</form>
```

And the page `inserting.php` will be like this:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        
        $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO people ('id', 'name', 'mother', 'address', 'city') VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[mother]', '', '$_POST[address]', '$_POST[city]')");
        $log = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO log (id, name, date, time) VALUES (NULL, $_POST[name], $date, $time)");

        echo $_POST['name'] . "was successfully inserted on" . $time . "of" . $date; . "."
    }

?>
```

What is wrong? How to do it?

Comment: id columns not needed on insert if auto-incrementing primary keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use raw `$_POST` in you queries! Never!
2. Use prepared statements to insert user data.
3. Always check for query result and read from `mysqli_error()` to check what is wrong.

In this case you're not putting `$_POST[name]` in `'` so it'll lead to syntax error. Also in first query you are using `'` instead of ` to wrap column names.

Comment: Thanks, Elon! I've never thought the problem was because of syntax errors.
I thought it was more complex to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks for column and table names,not quotes.Assuming auto increment id.Also quote you POST names.

```
INSERT INTO people (`name`, `mother`, `address`, `city`) 
VALUES ('$_POST['name']', '$_POST['mother']', '', '$_POST'[address']', '$_POST['city']')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column *id* of your table *log* is a primary key, you get an error because PKs can't be NULL.

And your query is:

```
$log = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO log (id, name, date, time) VALUES (NULL, $_POST[name], $date, $time)");
```